# How to re-render a React component. Next js 14

Tags: next.js13, next-auth

I am using Nexjt js.14 and in my navigator component, I have an element that changes depending on whether the auth cookie exists. Obviously works on reload.

**The element:** `` <Link className={`a  text-white hover:text-blue-600`} href={ ses.session?.user.username ? '/profile' : '/signin'}> { ses.session?.user.username ? 'Profile' : 'Sign In'}</Link> ``

**The sign-in process:**

```
   try{
   console.log("User:", user, psw)
   const SignInData = await signIn('credentials',{
       username:user,
       password:psw,
       redirect:false
   });
  if(SignInData?.error)
  {
   setEr({error:'Wrong username or password', state: 'visible'})
   setSign('Sign in')

}
  else
  {
   path.refresh()
   path.push('/profile')
  }
```

Ps. I swear it used to work, then at one point it just stoped.